# Commands for colouring in categories in R in different colours?

Tags: r, colors, boxplot

I need to colour in some categories in the same colour in a boxplot in R but have no clue how to do so. There are 8 categories and i need 4 of them in one colour, 2 in another colour and the remaining two one colour each. The problem i have is that they are not in order, i.e. 1,5-one colour, 3,4,6,8 one colour and then 7-one colour and 2-one colour. ANY HELP?????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `col` argument to `boxplot`:

```
boxplot(count~spray, data=InsectSprays, col=c("white", "green", "green", "white", "blue", "yellow"))
```

Comment: THANK you! that worked, i definitely saw a lot of information on the "col" function but didnt know that it had to be included in the bracket!